# OpenCV: Calculate contrast of a pixel (region), and merge based on comparing contrast

Tags: python, opencv

Is there a method in OpenCV for calculating a "contrast" value on a per-pixel basis?
E.g. by calculating the standard deviation of all surrounding pixels in a [n:n] region surrounding that pixel?

In a next step, I would like to calculate these values for two images, and then merge them by comparing which picture has the higher contrast, pixel by pixel.

The aim is to create a simple form of focus stacking (actually, a quicker preview of the eventual focus stacking results). The algorithms I found are always based on edge detection, which discards areas of less pronounced contrast completely. With what I imagine, there would always be a result, even if one image is a smooth gradient, and the other an ever so slightly grainy structure.

Comment: have you tried cv.meanStdDev to calculate standard deviation?

Comment: grayscale erode and dilate for a simple min/max "kernel", then calculate the per-pixel difference. that gives you the "range". might be good enough.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to do that on both images, then subtract and threshold to get a mask I can apply before merging.